# Any Decent Open Source XSLT designers for XSL-FO output [ WYSIWYG style]

Tags: xslt, wysiwyg, xsl-fo, apache-fop

We are planning to render millions of pdf's using Apache FOP by using XSL-FO as input.

Is there a decent XSLT WYSIWYG designer that allows to easily design an XSLT that will transform the XML input data to the XSL-FO required for processing by FOP?

I see a lot of commercial ones - Ecrion , Antenna House.. Any open source ones?

Answer (score 0):

The only somewhat decent editor that I have found is [MiniScribus Scribe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wysiwyg-edit/) but I gut stuck with it at the point of wanting to put a horizontal line and the opened odt file lost its table format in Scribe... it says that it doesnt support yet headers/footers and table borders... not so decent.

There are some converters that could be of good use, like [html 2 fo](http://html2fo.sourceforge.net/) and [odt to fo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/office2fo/) converters but the fo code generated by them returned a lot of exceptions from the Apache's FOP processor. The odt/html file with which I was testing had only a table, two horizontal lines and some unformatted text and only one page.

These tools, the convertors and the editor as well are now in beta phase so maybe there will a decent solution, so far I have not been able to find it.